# unshelving team explorer everywhere

Tags: tfs, team-explorer-everywhere, shelveset, unshelve

I'm trying to unshelve a shelveset using the command line with team explorer everywhere. I keep receiving this error:

```
An error occurred: TF400016: Unshelve with Merge is not supported on the version of Team Foundation Server on which your team project is hosted.
```

The shelveset is on the same branch as the one I'm trying to unshelve onto. I've run `tf undo -recursive .` before trying to unshelve and it tells me there are no pending changes, so I'm unsure why it is trying to merge. Has anyone had any success with this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you've modified the permissions on the files it may be reading that as a pending change

Comment: Thanks @SwankSwashbucklers. I just tried that. I deleted all the files, fetch latest and then immediately try to unshelve.

Comment: It didn't. Sorry I forgot to add that part

Comment: What is the command that you're actually executing?  Are you trying to specify a path?

Comment: `tf unshelve "test shelve"` I've also tried specifying the workspace but it doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 1):

Has the file changed in tfs since the shelve set was created?  I have seen the same problem if you try to unshelve a set from previous version of the file over a subsequent version.  To resolve, you can pull the code that matches the shelve set, then unshelve, then get the latest code and the merge will happen correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike. I don't think it's working though. I made sure to get latest on both computers then made a quick test shelve and still wasn't able to unshelve it.